# MYSQL - Updating a SET Value

Tags: mysql, database, set

Say for example you had a CD Database, where you wanted to increase the CD prices of all CD's with the genre 'Pop' by 10%. However the type Genre is a SET. Where it can be in multiple genre's, such as RnB and Rock.

My code is as follows:

```
UPDATE CD
set price = price * 1.1
WHERE genre = 'Pop';
```

However my code is only updating rows where the Genre is ONLY pop. If the Genre is 'Rock,Pop,RnB', it is not updated. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `LIKE` ([Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)):

```
... WHERE genre LIKE '%Pop%'
```

This will match if your genre is "Rock,Pop,RnB."

You should be aware that you are using a non-normalized structure. A better design would be to have a genre reference table:

**CD_Genre** (CD, Genre)

Comment: Careful! If you use this solution, ensure that you don't have any genre names which are substrings of other genre names. For example, "Popular" will be matched by `'%Pop%'`, and "Dubstep" will be matched by `'%Dub%'`.

Answer (score 1):

use like keyword

```
UPDATE CD set price = price * 1.1 WHERE genre like '%Pop%';
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to access SET values in queries is FIND_IN_SET:

```
UPDATE CD
set price = price * 1.1
where FIND_IN_SET('Pop', `genre`)
```

More information about FIND_IN_SET can be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set